# How to find mobile WiFi settings using browser

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Is there any way to get mobile connectivity settings from a website?
I want to check connection type (3G\4G\WiFi) and if this is WiFi - what security method is it using?

Is this possible? and how?

Edit: If it's not possible, can I "pop out" the WiFi setting screen if the user confirms it using web?

Comment: not really, `navigator.connection` doesn't work anywhere. you can still look at network timings for guidance on bandwidth and latency, but there's no way to tell the type of wifi network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API).

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
var type = connection.type;
```

where type can be one of bluetooth, cellular, ethernet, none, wifi, wimax, other, unknown.

Unfortunately [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=network%20information%20api) is very limited.

Comment: very limited, only chrome for Android support that apparently.